# Using primitive roots show that for any prime there's $n$ that the eqn $x^n \equiv x+1 \pmod{p}$ has an integer solution

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, cryptography

> Using primitive roots show that for any prime $p > 3$ there exists $n \in {2, 3,..., p − 2}$ such that the polynomial equation $x^n \equiv x+1 \pmod{p}$ has an integer solution.

How do I do this?

Comment: For some $x$, or for arbitrary $x$?

Comment: If $g$ is a primitive root what can you say about $g+1$? Reality check: This is where you need the assumption $p>3$.

Comment: you mind explaining the reality check assumption ? can a prime p have primitive root p -1 (except p = 3)?

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is a primitive root $\forall y\in\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}  $  $ \exists 1<\alpha<p$ such that $y=x^\alpha$.

So there is $n$ such that $x+1=x^n$